# is it incorrect to define an hashcode of an object as the sum, multiplication, whatever, of all class variables hashcodes?

Tags: c#, java, .net, hashcode

Let's say I have the following class:

```
class ABC {
    private int myInt = 1;
    private double myDouble = 2;
    private String myString = "123";
    private SomeRandomClass1 myRandomClass1 = new ...
    private SomeRandomClass2 myRandomClass2 = new ...

    //pseudo code
    public int myHashCode() {
        return 37 *
               myInt.hashcode() *
               myDouble.hashCode() *
               ... *
               myRandomClass.hashcode()
    }
}
```

Would this be a correct implementation of hashCode? This is not how I usually do it(I tend to follow Effective Java's guide-lines) but I always have the temptation to just do something like the above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "correct". Assuming that you're using the `hashCode()` of all the relevant `equals()`-defining fields, then yes, it's "correct". However, such formulas probably will not have a good distribution, and therefore would likely cause more collisions than otherwise, which will have a detrimental effect on performance.

Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, Item 9: Always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`

> While the recipe in this item yields reasonably good hash functions, it does not yield state-of-the-art hash functions, nor do Java platform libraries provide such hash functions as of release 1.6. Writing such hash functions is a research topic, best left to mathematicians and computer scientists. [...Nonetheless,] the techniques described in this item should be adequate for most applications.

It may not require a lot of mathematical power to evaluate how good your proposed hash function is, but why even bother? Why not just follow something that has been anecdotally proven to be adequate in practice?

#### Josh Bloch's recipe

- Store some constant nonzero value, say 17, in an `int` variable called `result`.
- Compute an `int` hashcode `c` for each field:

  - If the field is a `boolean`, compute `(f ? 1 : 0)`
  - If the field is a `byte, char, short, int`, compute `(int) f`
  - If the field is a `long`, compute `(int) (f ^ (f >>> 32))`
  - If the field is a `float`, compute `Float.floatToIntBits(f)`
  - If the field is a `double`, compute `Double.doubleToLongBits(f)`, then hash the resulting `long` as in above.
  - If the field is an object reference and this class's `equals` method compares the field by recursively invoking `equals`, recursively invoke `hashCode` on the field. If the value of the field is `null`, return 0.
  - If the field is an array, treat it as if each element is a separate field. If every element in an array field is significant, you can use one of the `Arrays.hashCode` methods added in release 1.5.
- Combine the hashcode `c` into `result` as follows: `result = 31 * result + c;`

Now, of course that recipe is rather complicated, but luckily, you don't have to reimplement it every time, thanks to [`java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) (and [`com.google.common.base.Objects`](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Objects.java) provides a convenient vararg variant).

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] {
           myInt,    //auto-boxed
           myDouble, //auto-boxed
           myRandomClass,
    });
}
```

#### See also

- [`Object.hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

  > It is *not* required that if two objects are unequal according to the `equals(java.lang.Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. *However,* the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Comment: Why not use the Commons Lang HashCodeBuilder?

Comment: Decent IDE's like Eclipse have also a nice hashcode (and equals) generator.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this sort of things is allowable by the contract. But so is always returning `1`. There is a compile time flag in HotSpot to always return `1` for the identity hash vale. Such choices will, however, produce poor performance.

There is a particular problem with multiplication. Not only will a 0 hash value from a component annihilate the value, but powers of two will progressively zero the lower bits.

Commutative operators have the problem that rearrangements of values will cause a clash.

If there is a particular relationship between hash values of components, then addition will be particularly bad. `(4, 6)` and `(2, 8)` clashing, for instance.

Comment: What is the identity hash value?

Comment: @devoured elysium The hash value is guaranteed to be the same for a particuler instance. From `System.identityHashCOde` or unoverridden `Object.hashCode`.

Comment: Addition is massively better than the xor which I've often seen used in situations requiring commutativity.  In languages which do not have a numeric type that is specified operates as a wrapping algebraic ring, xor has the advantage of being closed on the integers, but in Java addition is also closed.  Although (x+x) loses one bit of hash value from x, it's not nearly as bad as (x^x) which loses 32.  For situations involving things like arbitrary sets of hashed points, something like ((x*3)|1)*y may be better than e.g. x*31+y, since {(0,0),(1,1)} will be distinct from {(0,1),(1,0)}.

Answer (score 1):

No, but in practice it is almost certainly not a good idea. Most importantly you are not allowed to modify any of the fields that you use in the hash code. They all have to be constant.

If you modify one, this can happen: You insert the objecy in a HashSet, you change a fields, and then test if the object is in the HashSet. Although it is in there, due to the fact that the hash code changed, HashSet will not find it!

Comment: That's a good point, but that's a Collections Framework contract, regardless of `hashCode` formula.

Comment: I think this probably applies to most cases outside the Collection Framework as well. In fact, are you aware of any use case that copes with a dynamically changing hash code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably much too late to this party, but.....

The problem with your hash function can be described by the commutative law of multiplication. - [khan academy link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/in-in-class-6th-math-cbse/x06b5af6950647cd2:whole-numbers/x06b5af6950647cd2:commutative-property/v/commutative-law-of-multiplication)

That is - a * b * c == c * b * a.

So by only multiplying you remove the uniqueness of the order.  This means you are much more likely to get collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that unless you can guarantee that the product is a prime number you might get collision (though probably rare) between resulting hashcodes for an object

Comment: There's absolutely no reason why a hashcode would have to be a prime number. Besides, something that is a product is, by its very definition, not a prime number.

Comment: @jqno: mathematically, yes, but limited precision changes things a bit. `7 * 613566757 == 3` is prime.

Comment: @polygenelubricants Sure, but do you wanna base a hashCode implementation on that :) ?