# What is a best practice of writing hash function in java?

Tags: java, hash

I'm wondering what is the best practice for writing #hashCode() method in java.
Good description can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05273.html). Is it that good?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation

Comment: I don't think it really is as current post has a bit wider scope.

Comment: Can you please clarify how your question is different, then? They look the same to me.

Comment: @mmyers: If we're talking about question, then difference lies at least in their formulation. As for contents, many answers there do answer this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735037/is-it-incorrect-to-define-an-hashcode-of-an-object-as-the-sum-multiplication-wh

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A great reference for an implementation of `hashCode()` is described in the book [Effective Java](http://web.archive.org/web/20050404005610/http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/index.html). After you understand the theory behind generating a good hash function, you may check [HashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) from Apache commons lang, which implements what's described in the book. From the docs:

> This class enables a good hashCode
>   method to be built for any class. It
>   follows the rules laid out in the book
>   Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.
>   Writing a good hashCode method is
>   actually quite difficult. This class
>   aims to simplify the process.

Answer (score 61):

Here's a quote from *Effective Java 2nd Edition*, Item 9: "Always override `hashCode` when you override `equals`":

> While the recipe in this item yields reasonably good hash functions, it does not yield state-of-the-art hash functions, nor do Java platform libraries provide such hash functions as of release 1.6. Writing such hash functions is a research topic, best left to mathematicians and computer scientists. [... Nonetheless,] the techniques described in this item should be adequate for most applications.

#### Josh Bloch's recipe

- Store some constant nonzero value, say 17, in an `int` variable called `result`
- Compute an `int` hashcode `c` for each field `f` that defines `equals`:

  - If the field is a `boolean`, compute `(f ? 1 : 0)`
  - If the field is a `byte, char, short, int`, compute `(int) f`
  - If the field is a `long`, compute `(int) (f ^ (f >>> 32))`
  - If the field is a `float`, compute `Float.floatToIntBits(f)`
  - If the field is a `double`, compute `Double.doubleToLongBits(f)`, then hash the resulting `long` as in above
  - If the field is an object reference and this class's `equals` method compares the field by recursively invoking `equals`, recursively invoke `hashCode` on the field. If the value of the field is `null`, return 0
  - If the field is an array, treat it as if each element is a separate field. If every element in an array field is significant, you can use one of the `Arrays.hashCode` methods added in release 1.5
- Combine the hashcode `c` into `result` as follows: `result = 31 * result + c;`

Now, of course that recipe is rather complicated, but luckily, you don't have to reimplement it every time, thanks to [`java.util.Arrays.hashCode(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

```
@Override public int hashCode() {
    return Arrays.hashCode(new Object[] {
           myInt,    //auto-boxed
           myDouble, //auto-boxed
           myString,
    });
}
```

As of Java 7 there is a convenient varargs variant in [`java.util.Objects.hash(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash(java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 0):

It's good, as @leonbloy says, to understand it well.  Even then, however, one "best" practice is to simply let your IDE write the function for you.  It won't be optimal under some circumstances - and in some very rare circumstances it won't even be good - but for most situations, it's easy, repeatable, error-free, and as good (as a hash code) as it needs to be.  Sure, read the docs and understand it well - but don't complicate it unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, not an optimal solution when using entities in EJB or alike cases.