# HashMap implementation in Java. How does the bucket index calculation work?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am looking at the implementation of `HashMap` in Java and am stuck at one point.
How is the `indexFor` function calculated?

```
static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
   return h & (length-1);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not calculating the *hash*, it's calculating the *bucket*.

The expression `h & (length-1)` does a bit-wise `AND` on `h` using `length-1`, which is like a bit-mask, to return only the low-order bits of `h`, thereby making for a super-fast variant of `h % length`.

Comment: Can you please explain this calculation here ?

Comment: Does this assume that `length` is a power of 2?

Comment: @LarsH Well, it would be far better if it was a power of 2, then you'd get a clean chop off of the high-order bits. As it happens, the implementation of HashMap starts with size 16 and does indeed multiply by two when resizing. It would still work if not a power of two, but you would want as many bits "on" as possible for `length -1` to balance the spread between buckets

Comment: So does it mean that in HashMap there is always 16 buckets (initial capacity)?
Because if it is `h % length`, then no more buckets can be created.

Comment: @lex I don’t understand your question, but the capacity (the quantity of buckets), which is stored in `length`, doubles if the buckets are “too full”. The algorithm relies on `length` always being a power of 2. `16` was chosen as using the Goldielocks principle (not to big and not too small)

Comment: @Bohemian
When i try this `indexFor(18,7)` it return 2 but `18 % 7` return 4, why would you say it's `a super-fast variant of h % length`

Comment: @unclebob as per my previous comment, **the algorithm relies on `length` being a power of 2** (which is always the case for HashMap). 7 is not a power of 2.

Answer (score 133):

The hash itself is calculated by the `hashCode()` method of the object you're trying to store.

What you see here is calculating the "bucket" to store the object based on the hash `h`. Ideally, to evade collisions, you would have the same number of buckets as is the maximum achievable value of `h` - but that could be too memory demanding. Therefore, you usually have a lower number of buckets with a danger of collisions.

If `h` is, say, 1000, but you only have 512 buckets in your underlying array, you need to know where to put the object. Usually, a `mod` operation on `h` would be enough, but that's too slow. Given the internal property of `HashMap` that the underlying array *always* has number of buckets equal to `2^n`, the Sun's engineers could use the idea of `h & (length-1)`, it does a [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) with a number consisting of all `1`'s, practically reading only the `n` lowest bits of the hash (which is the same as doing `h mod 2^n`, only *much* faster).

Example:

```
     hash h: 11 1110 1000  -- (1000 in decimal)
   length l: 10 0000 0000  -- ( 512 in decimal)
      (l-1): 01 1111 1111  -- ( 511 in decimal - it will always be all ONEs)
h AND (l-1): 01 1110 1000  -- ( 488 in decimal which is a result of 1000 mod 512)
```

Comment: Does it make sense now, or should I elaborate more on the internals?

Comment: _Very_ well explained.  I'm impressed.

Comment: Does this mean that a hash bucket could contain keys with different `hashCodes` if the lowest 9 or so bits agree, but the higher bits are different?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Yes, that's correct. That's one of the main reasons why a [good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738886/what-is-a-best-practice-of-writing-hash-function-in-java) [hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation) [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624192/good-hash-function-for-strings) multiplies it's result by a prime number - it tries to achieve very different hashes even when the values differ by a little.

Comment: @Slanec Thank you. This is one of the clearest answers I've seen on SO. (+1).

Comment: The best explanation of the bucket calculation on the web. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PetrJaneček would mind explaining this?
If L != 2^n? then L-1 will not have all the bits set to 1 right?
Say L = 511 and not 512, then?

Comment: @KJ Sudarshan Exactly correct. And in that case the trick with `&` wouldn't work, but you could still use a normal modulo, `%`. The binary trickery is simply a performance trick.

Comment: I've always thought that each bucket held items with the same hashcode. There are a lot of articles out there that say this. But what you are saying here is that the hashcode gets a furthur map into buckets with mixed hashcodes. This makes more sense storagewise.

Answer (score 4):

The above answer is very good but I want to explain more why Java can use `indexFor` for create index

Example, I have a `HashMap` like this (this test is on Java7, I see Java8 change HashMap a lot but I think this logic still very good)

```
// Default length of "budget" (table.length) after create is 16 (HashMap#DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("A",1); // hash("A")=69, indexFor(hash,table.length)=69&(16-1) = 5
hashMap.put("B",2); // hash("B")=70, indexFor(hash,table.length)=70&(16-1) = 6
hashMap.put("P",3); // hash("P")=85, indexFor(hash,table.length)=85&(16-1) = 5
hashMap.put("A",4); // hash("A")=69, indexFor(hash,table.length)=69&(16-1) = 5
hashMap.put("r", 4);// hash("r")=117, indexFor(hash,table.length)=117&(16-1) = 5
```

You can see the index of entry with key `"A"` and object with key `"P"` and object with key `"r"` have same index (**= 5**). And here is the debug result after I execute code above

[image]

Table in the image is here

```
public class HashMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>, Cloneable, Serializable {
    transient HashMap.Entry<K, V>[] table;
    ...
}
```

=> I see
If index are **different**, new entry will add to table
If index is **same** and `hash` is **same**, new value will update
If index is **same** and `hash` is **different**, new entry will point to old entry (like a `LinkedList`). Then you know why `Map.Entry` have field `next`

```
static class Entry<K, V> implements java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> {
        ...
        HashMap.Entry<K, V> next;
}
```

You can verify it again by read the code in `HashMap`.

As now, you can think that `HashMap` will **never need to change** the size (16) because `indexFor()` always return value <= 15 but it **not** correct.
If you look at `HashMap` code

```
 if (this.size >= this.threshold ...) {
      this.resize(2 * this.table.length);
```

`HashMap` will resize table (double table length) when `size` >= `threadhold`

What is `threadhold`? `threadhold` is calculated below

```
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
static final float DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR = 0.75F;
...
this.threshold = (int)Math.min((float)capacity * this.loadFactor, 1.07374182E9F); // if capacity(table.length) = 16 => threadhold = 12
```

What is the `size`? `size` is calculated below.
Of course, `size` here **is not** `table.length` .
Any time you put new entry to `HashMap` and `HashMap` need to create new entry (note that `HashMap` don't create new entry when the key is same, it just override new value for existed entry)  then `size++`

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    ...
    ++this.size;
}
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 3):

It is calculating the bucket of the hash map where the entry (key-value pair) will be stored. The bucket id is `hashvalue/buckets length`.

A hash map consists of buckets; objects will be placed in these buckets based on the bucket id.

Any number of objects can actually fall into the same bucket based on their `hash code / buckets length` value. This is called a 'collision'.

If many objects fall into the same bucket, while searching their equals() method will be called to disambiguate.

The number of collisions is indirectly proportional to the bucket's length.

Answer (score -3):

bucket_index = (i.hashCode() && 0x7FFFFFFFF) % hashmap_size does the trick