# Python LPTHW: What is this loop statement doing in his function

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm following the book "Learn Python The Hard Way" And I don't understand what is going on in this function in Exercise 39.

```
def new(num_buckets=256): #So the function is made and its named "new" and the argument inside is
    """Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = [] #then it creates an empty list and names it aMap 
    for i in range(0, num_buckets): #This loop is created named i and it is ranging from 0-255.
        aMap.append([]) #then it adds a list inside our aMap variable.
    return aMap
```

I don't know what the "for i in range(0,num_bucketss) is doing here. What is it doing the append command?

Comment: Add a line `print(i)` and think how aMap changes each time. Also, think about the variable name `num_buckets`...

Comment: I've tried adding a print command. It gives me this though: "<function new at 0x01DB6870>"

Comment: Well, then you're definitely doing *something* wrong -- did you use the exact print statement I suggested? Being able to make looping explicit is helpful while learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's adding as many empty lists in `aMap` as `num_buckets` specifies. So, if `num_buckets = 5`, `aMap` will be a list of 5 empty lists.

As for why it is doing that, we'll need more context.

EDIT:

Seeing the [context](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html), it's doing this to create a number of empty buckets for the hashmap. You can read more about how a hashmap uses buckets here:
[What is meant by number of buckets in the HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636576/what-is-meant-by-number-of-buckets-in-the-hashmap)

Comment: It's used to create our own dictionary module:http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html . so if it was num_buckets = 3. It's basically making 3 lists inside a list? Like [ [],[],[] ] ?

Comment: @Lia: Correct, it would make `[[],[],[]]`. Seeing the context, it's doing this because a dictionary operates using a number of `buckets`. See edit for more details.

Comment: Ok I have one more question. How is the "for i in range(0, num_buckets): applied to aMap.append([])? I thought since the "for loop" is named "i" that it has to be applied somewhere in aMap.append() to have it create 255 lists, but I'm thinking aMap.append([]) has no relationship to the loop

Comment: `i` is the loop counter here. There is no requirement that you have to use the counter in the loop. For example:     
`for i in range(1, 100):
  print "Hello World!"  `

Comment: ahh ok I get it. Thanks for the help. This has been bothering me all day and I couldnt understand why. The book didn't go as in depth with loops as I would have wanted. Your Hello World example was very useful.