# Number of entries in HashMap bucket

Tags: java, hashmap, bucket

Is there a way to determine what buckets do we have in `HashMap`, and how many entries do they contain?

Comment: hashmap -> keyset -> lenght?

Comment: @FranMontero this would get you all they keys, the OP is asking for the buckets

Comment: @asdfzcx this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636576/what-is-meant-by-number-of-buckets-in-the-hashmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by reflection but it is very jdk specific. This one works with small maps Java 8 but will probably break when the map gets bigger because I believe Java 8 uses a hybrid mechanism when the buckets get full.

```
private void buckets(HashMap<String, String> m) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    // Pull out the table.
    Field f = m.getClass().getDeclaredField("table");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    Object[] table = (Object[]) f.get(m);
    int bucket = 0;
    // Walk it.
    for (Object o : table) {
        if (o != null) {
            // At least one in this bucket.
            int count = 1;
            // What's in the `next` field?
            Field nf = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("next");
            nf.setAccessible(true);
            Object n = nf.get(o);
            if (n != null) {
                do {
                    // Count them.
                    count += 1;
                } while ((n = nf.get(n)) != null);
            }
            System.out.println("Bucket " + bucket + " contains " + count + " entries");
        }
        bucket += 1;
    }
}

public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
    String[] data = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "five"};
    for (String s : data) {
        m.put(s, s);
    }
    buckets(m);
}
```

Prints:

```
Bucket 7 contains 2 entries
Bucket 13 contains 2 entries
Bucket 14 contains 1 entries
```

Answer (score 2):

Not directly: this is an implementation detail hidden through use of private fields.

If you have access to source code of your JDK, you could use *reflection* API to access [private variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1196192/335858) of your `HashMap<K,V>`, which would let you get bucket count and the content of individual buckets. Your code would be non-portable, though, because it would break encapsulation of a library class.