# How to remove duplicates from ArrayList of type Object?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashset, linkedhashset

I want to remove duplicates from `ArrayList` of type `Alerts` where `Alerts` is a class.

**Class Alerts -**

```
public class Alerts implements Parcelable {
    String date = null;
    String alertType = null;
    String discription = null;

    public Alerts() {

    }

    public Alerts(String date, String alertType, String discription) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.alertType = alertType;
        this.discription = discription;
    }
}
```

**Here is how I added the elements -**

```
ArrayList<Alerts> alert = new ArrayList<Alerts>();
Alerts obAlerts = new Alerts();

obAlerts = new Alerts();
obAlerts.date = Date1.toString();
obAlerts.alertType = "Alert Type 1";
obAlerts.discription = "Some Text";
alert.add(obAlerts);

obAlerts = new Alerts();
obAlerts.date = Date2.toString();
obAlerts.alertType = "Alert Type 1";
obAlerts.discription = "Some Text";
alert.add(obAlerts);
```

**What I want to remove from them-**

I want all alerts which have unique `obAlerts.date` and `obAlerts.alertType`. In other words, remove duplicate `obAlerts.date` and `obAlerts.alertType` alerts.

**I tried this -**

```
Alerts temp1, temp2;
String macTemp1, macTemp2, macDate1, macDate2;

for(int i=0;i<alert.size();i++)
 {    
    temp1 = alert.get(i);  
    macTemp1=temp1.alertType.trim(); 
    macDate1 = temp1.date.trim();

    for(int j=i+1;j<alert.size();j++)
    {

         temp2 = alert.get(j);  
        macTemp2=temp2.alertType.trim();  
        macDate2 = temp2.date.trim();

        if (macTemp2.equals(macTemp1) && macDate1.equals(macDate2))  
        {   
           alert.remove(temp2);           
        } 

    }
 }
```

**I also tried-**

```
HashSet<Alerts> hs = new HashSet<Alerts>();
hs.addAll(obAlerts);
obAlerts.clear();
obAlerts.addAll(hs);
```

Comment: You want each object to have a different `date` **AND** a different `alertType`. So you have to remove the object if the `date` **OR** the `alertType` is the same for two objects.

Comment: @G.T. YES. How to remove such duplicates?

Comment: As you did. Just replace `&&` by `||` in the last `if`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First store your datas in array then split at as one by one string,, till the length of that data execute arry and compare with acyual data by if condition and retun it,,

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>(); 

for(int i=0;i<alert.size();i++)
{
    hs.add(alert.get(i).date + ","+ alert.get(i).alertType;
}

alert.clear();

String alertAll[] = null;
for (String s : hs) {   

    alertAll = s.split(",");
    obAlerts = new Alerts();
    obAlerts.date = alertAll[0];
    obAlerts.alertType = alertAll[1];
    alert.add(obAlerts);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example to illustrate?

Comment: @VedPrakash Don't do it yourself, unless you are studying Data Structures.

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify yourself how the class decides equality by overriding a pair of methods:

```
public class Alert {

    String date;
    String alertType;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if ((o == null) || (!(o instanceof Alert)))
            return false;
        }
        Alert alert = (Alert) o;
        return this.date.equals(alert.date)
                && this.alertType.equals(alert.alertType);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int dateHash;
        int typeHash;
        if (date == null) {
            dateHash = super.hashCode();
        } else {
            dateHash = this.date.hashCode();
        }
        if (alertType == null) {
            typeHash = super.hashCode();
        } else {
            typeHash = this.alertType.hashCode();
        }
        return dateHash + typeHash;
    }
}
```

You can then loop through your ArrayList and add elements if they aren't already there as `Collections.contains()` makes use of these methods.

```
public List<Alert> getUniqueList(List<Alert> alertList) {
    List<Alert> uniqueAlerts = new ArrayList<Alert>();
    for (Alert alert : alertList) {
        if (!uniqueAlerts.contains(alert)) {
            uniqueAlerts.add(alert);
        }
    }
    return uniqueAlerts;
}
```

However, after saying all that, you may want to revisit your design to use a Set or one of its family that doesn't allow duplicate elements. Depends on your project. [Here's a comparison of Collections types](http://codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-collections-framework-summary-table)

Comment: I want the equality of both `date` and `alertType`. So can I use `return this.date.equals(alert.date) && this.alertType.equals(alert.alertType);` in the `equals` method ?

Comment: You can use whatever conditions you like but make sure that you then include the `alertType` field in calculating the `hashCode`; the two methods must match up so that if `a.equals(b)` then `a.hashCode() equals b.hashCode()`

Comment: Instead of those looping Statemts for Unique list simply use  List<Alerts> depdupeCustomers = new ArrayList<Alerts>(
    new LinkedHashSet<Alerts>(alert));

Comment: The given example code can be improved. Never blindly do a cast and rely on the try-catch. Using Exceptions for control flow is an anti-pattern, because Exceptions are very very expensive to create. Plus, that equals method does not conform to the javadoc specification (compare the thread linked from my answer), since it will throw a `NullPointerException` when you pass `null` to it.

Comment: @indivisible What should be returned in a hashcode() method when alertType is also considered together with date ? Will this work - `int a = this.date.hashCode() + this.alertType.hashCode();return a;`

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu, edit made that addresses your issues.

Comment: @indivisible - No, my issue is to add `alertType` and `date` both for equality check. So please add `alertType` also.

Comment: @VedPrakash, That's up to you. `hashCode()` returns an `int` so any consistent calculation you perform with both field's hashCodes should work well.

Comment: @VedPrakash, Another edit; last one. You should be able to figure out the rest yourself

Comment: Probably speaking with my code reviewer voice right now, but that last revision of your `hashCode` method is inconsistent in that it will produce distinct results whenever at least one of the primary key fields is `null`. Eg. two instances where date is `null` und alertType is equal in both instances. Your implementation will deliver distinct hash values for those semantically identical instances because you fallback to `super.hashCode()` in case of `null`. However, let's leave the choice of a correct fallback value as an exercise to the OP, no? :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could add an arbitrary number to one of them but as you inferred, his code to work on not mine. Also, I just discovered my IDE's auto equals/hashCode generation wizard thanks to your link above. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Set<>`.  By nature, Sets do no include duplicates. You just need to make sure that you have a proper `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods.

Comment: See the update. I used HashSet but the duplicates are still there. Can you illustrate ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `Alerts` class, override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods to be dependent on the values of the fields you want to be primary keys. Afterwards, you can use a `HashSet` to store already seen instances while iterating over the `ArrayList`. When you find an instance which is not in the `HashSet`, add it to the `HashSet`, else remove it from the `ArrayList`. To make your life easier, you could switch to a `HashSet` altogether and be done with duplicates per se.

Beware that for overriding `hashCode` and `equals`, [some constraints apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738886/what-is-a-best-practice-of-writing-hash-function-in-java) has some helpful pointers on how to write good `hashCode` functions. An important lesson is that simply adding together all dependent fields' hashcodes is not sufficient because then swapping values between fields will lead to identical hashCodes which might not be desirable (compare swapping first name and last name). Instead, some sort of shifting-operation is usually done before adding the next atomic hash, eg. multiplying with a prime.

Comment: See the update. I tried HashSet with no success. Can you illustrate ?

Comment: @VedPrakash Overriding `hashCode` and `equals` in your `Alerts` class is **mandatory**. Without a proper hash-code operation in the key object, HashSet is worthless since it will base the decision "is it a duplicate?" on the native hash code, which is different for all distinct objects regardless of the value of the fields.

Comment: @VedPrakash Updated my answer to add information about how to write good `hashCode` functions.